# Performance penalties to deconstructing tuples in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, types, valuetuple

If we do

```
var (hello, world) = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
if (hello == "hello" && world == "world")
  Environment.Exit(0);
```

Does that incur any additional costs than just doing the following:

```
var helloAndWorld = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
if (helloAndWorld.Hello == "hello" && helloAndWorld.World == "world")
  Environment.Exit(0);
```

Or is it all syntatic sugar - the code that ends up being generated always uses Item1 and Item2.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: They always use `Item1` and `Item2`. The names are there for readability only and they are only available at compile time. IL shows they use `Item1` and `Item2` regardless of what you've named them (ValueTuple is a struct with fields like any other structs) - e.g. `valuetype [System.Runtime]System.ValueTuple``2<int32, int32>::Item1`

Comment: There's no performance penalty, the generated code is identical. You can also use `if (helloAndWorld == ("hello","world"))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are effectively the same generated *IL* with only minor *emitted* differences, **However**... they would likely be *jitted* and optimized to *exactly* the same instructions.

**Given**

```
private (String hello,string world) GetHelloAndWorldStrings() 
{ 
   return ("asdsd","sadfsdf");
}
    
...
        

public int Test1()
{
   var asd = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
   if (asd.hello == "hello" && asd.world == "world")
      return 1;
   return 0;
}

public int Test2()
{
   var (hello, world) = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
   if (hello == "hello" && world == "world")
      return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Would basically be *emitted* as

```
public int Test1()
{
    ValueTuple<string, string> helloAndWorldStrings = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
    if (helloAndWorldStrings.Item1 == "hello" && helloAndWorldStrings.Item2 == "world")
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int Test2()
{
    ValueTuple<string, string> helloAndWorldStrings = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
    string item = helloAndWorldStrings.Item1;
    string item2 = helloAndWorldStrings.Item2;
    if (item == "hello" && item2 == "world")
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[**You can check the IL out here**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqqmpZADgE5gBuAhsAKaYAUMCADJgBaMQQB7ADTZOmAO4DKEACYBKTAHFGwABJ9BAQQB2MgOpTZAZWDVtAcwDOLOSTKkiKe85gB2VgCI6lmT48iPSzoZADMfEI85AG47ewBfYicXLDBtYEwAFUZLYAQbWLJHZ3t6SkxvGUwAXiUVdX4BHX1DGRMzKxsYpOLMMBDWCoA6Xgbqmo8RwQ9MADIZ8p9ByWlKqvHl2UiCnux3BC6d3cwOA+cElG3sFLTM7OA4fO7Cy7JS1knhCRaFGuU1DUaugMKzaqQ60RepD67wBY0wEwB0zmXxWcI8GxkWyeOzcmH2kKOJ0u5ziQA==)

Here is an example of the *JIT ASM* in release

```
C.Test1()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: mov ecx, [0x11198648]
    L000a: mov esi, [0x1119864c]
    L0010: mov edx, [0x11198650]
    L0016: call System.String.Equals(System.String, System.String)
    L001b: test eax, eax
    L001d: je short L0038
    L001f: mov edx, [0x11198654]
    L0025: mov ecx, esi
    L0027: call System.String.Equals(System.String, System.String)
    L002c: test eax, eax
    L002e: je short L0038
    L0030: mov eax, 1
    L0035: pop esi
    L0036: pop ebp
    L0037: ret
    L0038: xor eax, eax
    L003a: pop esi
    L003b: pop ebp
    L003c: ret
```

vs

```
C.Test2()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: mov ecx, [0x11198648]
    L000a: mov esi, [0x1119864c]
    L0010: mov edx, [0x11198650]
    L0016: call System.String.Equals(System.String, System.String)
    L001b: test eax, eax
    L001d: je short L0038
    L001f: mov edx, [0x11198654]
    L0025: mov ecx, esi
    L0027: call System.String.Equals(System.String, System.String)
    L002c: test eax, eax
    L002e: je short L0038
    L0030: mov eax, 1
    L0035: pop esi
    L0036: pop ebp
    L0037: ret
    L0038: xor eax, eax
    L003a: pop esi
    L003b: pop ebp
    L003c: ret
```

<sub>*In short, the net gain of worrying about this.. minus 5 minutes of your life you'll never get back*</sub>

Comment: If you add 2 `int` properties into the mix of the tuple (`one` and `two`), I think the difference is more clearer, and the JIT (JIT ASM) in release finally shows some differences in generated code (`Test1` has less instructions).

Comment: @SpiritBob likely because of the copy of the value type.

Comment: Yes, versus just passing by reference. I have a silly question - how did you decode that `Test2` indeed emits a copy of the value tuple struct? (`string item = helloAndWorldStrings.Item1;` `string item2 = helloAndWorldStrings.Item1;`)

Answer (score 2):

There's a third option that is equivalent to the first:

```
  public int Test3()
  {
     var asd = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
     if (asd == ("hello", "world"))
        return 1;
     return 0;
  }
```

It equally thranslates to [(sharplab.io)](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetaN3gDgE4CWAbgIYAuApogBQgQAMiAFtQDYcD2ANMs0QB3boQ4ATAJSIA4tUoAJTjwCCAO3EB1URIDKlEmoDmAZzqSceXFhhW7IAOz0ARORPj3z/s5PlxAM3d/Z0kAbksrAF9sW3skYjVKRAAVahNKeHMIvBs7KwpCRDdxRABeWXklLm51LR1xfUNTc3DYvMRif3pisvK6Z3Zqr0RnETFxEIs29txHRAhWmeQnJkW7aJhIoA=):

```
public int Test3()
{
    ValueTuple<string, string> helloAndWorldStrings = GetHelloAndWorldStrings();
    if (helloAndWorldStrings.Item1 == "hello" && helloAndWorldStrings.Item2 == "world")
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[(sharplab.io)](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqqmpZADgE5gBuAhsAKaYAUMCADJgBaMQQB7ADTZOmAO4DKEACYBKTAHFGwABJ9BAQQB2MgOpTZAZWDVtAcwDOLOSTKkiKe85gB2VgCI6lmT48iPSzoZADMfEI85AG47ewBfYicXLDBtYEwAFUZLYHQbWLJHZ3t6SkxvGUwAXiUVdX4BHX1DGRMzKxsYpOLMMBDWCuqalg9eBv9MD0lpGUjbbp7SN0wELsXsdw415wSUOKA==)

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance int32 Test3 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2064
    // Code size 47 (0x2f)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string>
    )

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string> C::GetHelloAndWorldStrings()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: ldfld !0 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string>::Item1
    IL_000d: ldstr "hello"
    IL_0012: call bool [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
    IL_0017: brfalse.s IL_002d

    IL_0019: ldloc.0
    IL_001a: ldfld !1 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string>::Item2
    IL_001f: ldstr "world"
    IL_0024: call bool [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
    IL_0029: brfalse.s IL_002d

    IL_002b: ldc.i4.1
    IL_002c: ret

    IL_002d: ldc.i4.0
    IL_002e: ret
} // end of method C::Test3
```